# How do I assign more than 2 numerical categories in R to single response?

Tags: r, categories, numeric, levels

I am quite new to R. I have a hospital dataset where patients are assigned categories based on diagnosis. For example

- Patient# :      Disease classification
- 1 :             dis A/dis C
- 2 :            dis B
- 3 :             dis A/dis B/dis C

And so on with 8 diseases in total. The "/" here represents the presence of more than 1 disease. I want  to categorize them numerically such that dis A=1, dis B=2 and so on. The above data needs to be:

- Patient#:     Disease classification
- 1:              1/3
- 2:              2
- 3:              1/2/3

I have tried it with sapply, as a factor with levels but the best I can get is a correct classification with only single diseases. The combination diseases are returning a NULL value. Is there a way to do this? Please help!

Here is a sample:

```r
structure(list(Classification = c("IHD/other/cardiopulmonary", 
"IHD", "hypertensive", "IHD/other", "IHD/other", "IHD/other/CVA"
), Comorbidities = c("DM", "HT+DM", "HT+DM", NA, NA, "HT+DM"), 
    Diagnosis = c("CORONARY ARTERY DISEASE WITH MITRAL REGURGITATION WITH TRICUSPID REGURGITATION WITH PULOMNARY HYPERTENSION WITH DYSFUNCTION LEFT VENTRICLE WITH DIABETES MELLITUS", 
    "ACUTE CORONARY SYNDROME WITH ANTERIOR WALL MYOCARDIAL INFARCTION WITH CARDIOGENIC SHOCK WITH BLEEDING DIATHESIS WITH DIABETES MELLITUS WITH HYPERTENSION", 
    "ASPIRATION PNEUMONTIS WITH RESPIRATORY FALIURE WITH HYPERTENSION WITH HYPONATERMIA WITH DIABETES MELLITUS", 
    "ACUTE CORONARY SYNDROME WITH RIGHT BUNDLE BRANCH BLOCK WITH ANTERIOR WALL MYOCARDIAL INFARCTION WITH CARDIOGENIC SHOCK", 
    "COMPLETE HEART BLOCK WITH CARDIAC ARREST WITH INTERIOR WALL MYOCARDIAL INFARCTION", 
    "DIABETES MELLITUS WITH CORONARY ARTERY DISEASE WITH HYPERTENSION SYSTEMIC WITH ATRIAL FIBRILATION WITH PULMONARY TUBERCULOSIS WITH CEREBRO VASCULAR ACCIDENT WITH CARDIOGENIC SHOCK"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I tried using the car solution given previously (I can't see it now) but had the same problem

Comment: Can you show an example dataset? Best use `dput(head(YOURDATA)) `. This makes it easier to build sn apropriate answer and test it.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: added as an edit

Comment: @user16584364 I removed the `car` solution because I saw it didn't work. Now I updated my solution with your sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one base R option which should work for any number of diseases without manually specifying a number for them.

```
#split the string on '/'
split_vals <- strsplit(df$Classification, '/')
#Get the unique values
all_vals <- unique(unlist(split_vals))
#Use match to get a unique number for each value.
df$Classification <- sapply(split_vals, function(x) 
                            paste(match(x, all_vals),collapse = '/'))
df

# Classification Comorbidities Diagnosis                                                                 
#  <chr>          <chr>         <chr>                                                                     
#1 1/2/3          DM            CORONARY ARTERY DISEASE WITH MITRAL REGURGITATION WITH TRICUSPID REGURGIT…
#2 1              HT+DM         ACUTE CORONARY SYNDROME WITH ANTERIOR WALL MYOCARDIAL INFARCTION WITH CAR…
#3 4              HT+DM         ASPIRATION PNEUMONTIS WITH RESPIRATORY FALIURE WITH HYPERTENSION WITH HYP…
#4 1/2            NA            ACUTE CORONARY SYNDROME WITH RIGHT BUNDLE BRANCH BLOCK WITH ANTERIOR WALL…
#5 1/2            NA            COMPLETE HEART BLOCK WITH CARDIAC ARREST WITH INTERIOR WALL MYOCARDIAL IN…
#6 1/2/5          HT+DM         DIABETES MELLITUS WITH CORONARY ARTERY DISEASE WITH HYPERTENSION SYSTEMIC…
```

Comment: Great use of function `match`.

Comment: ok, so this partially works, it gives me 11 different kinds of numerical values. So for example, IHD=1, IHD/OTHER=1/2 but OTHER on its own is 8 instead of being 2. I changed the classifications to all caps to avoid further confusion as well. Any way around this?

Comment: There can be some whitespaces in the data. Do `all_vals <- trimws(unique(unlist(split_vals)))` and also instead of `x` in `match(x...)` use `match(trimws(x), ...)`.

Comment: Finally worked, I went back to the original data in excel and changed it all to uppercase there before reimporting to r. Fixed the problem. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(string = c("1 dis A/dis C 2 dis B 3 dis A/dis B/dis C", "dis A/dis B"), pattern = c('dis A' = '1', 'dis B' = '2','dis C' = '3'))
[1] "1 1/3 2 2 3 1/2/3" "1/2"
```

**Update**

With the example data:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(string = df$Classification, pattern = c('IHD' = '1', 'other' = '2','cardiopulmonary' = '3', 'hypertensive' = '4', 'CVA'='5'))
[1] "1/2/3" "1"     "4"     "1/2"   "1/2"   "1/2/5"
```

So, in order to update your data, you can do:

```r
df$Classification <- stringr::str_replace_all(string = df$Classification, pattern = c('IHD' = '1', 'other' = '2','cardiopulmonary' = '3', 'hypertensive' = '4', 'CVA'='5'))
```

Comment: In stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing. -that is the error I get and then the result is just lots of random numbers in the column

Comment: @user16584364 I do not get any warning or error; what is `class(df$Classification)` for you?

Answer (score 0):

simple subset with `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
dis <- c('dis A','dis B','dis C','dis D','dis E','dis F','dis G','dis H')
class <- 1:8

library(dplyr)
library(qdap)

dt %>% 
  mutate(`Disease classification` = mgsub(dis,class,`Disease classification`))

# dt %>% 
#   mutate(`NEW Disease classification` = mgsub(dis,class,`Disease classification`))
```

Comment: I loaded both packages, but am getting a "could not find mgsub" error.

Comment: I did that already, and library(qdap) as well. Also tried restarting R session

Comment: if you get "could not find mgsub" after load library means that it was not installed correctly